# To find out whether every letter in word B appear in word A, which is the fastest func in php

Tags: php, sorting, strpos

I got three funcs:
_sort, _strpos, _array_int

```
<?php
class timer{
    private $_start;
    private $_end;
    public function program_begin(){
        $this->_start = microtime(true);
    }
    public function program_end(){
        $this->_end = microtime(true);
    }
    public function get_time(){
        $time_use = ($this->_end - $this->_start)*1000;
        echo $time_use."ms\n";
    }
};
$t = new timer();
$test_cnt = $argv[1];
$s_len1 = $s_len2 = $argv[2];
$t->program_begin();
for($j = 0; $j<$test_cnt; $j++){
    for($i = 0; $i < $s_len1; $i++)
        $s1 .= chr(rand()%26+97);

    for($i = 0; $i < $s_len2; $i++)
        $s2 .= chr(rand()%26+97);

    $flag = call_user_func($argv[3],$s1, $s2);
    $s1=$s2="";
}
$t->program_end();
$t->get_time();

function _sort($s1, $s2){
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s1); $i++)
        $arr[] = $s1[$i];

    sort($arr);

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s2); $i++)
        if(!search_part($arr, $s2[$i]))
            return false;

    return true;

}
function search_part($arr, $key){
    $s = 0; 
    $e = count($arr)-1;
    while($s<=$e){
        $m = (int)(($s+$e)/2);
        if($arr[$m] > $key)
            $e = $m-1;

        if($arr[$m] < $key)
            $s = $m+1;

        if($arr[$m] == $key)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function _strpos($s1, $s2){
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s2); $i++)
        if(strpos($s1,$s2[$i]) === false)
            return false;

    return true;
}

function _array($s1, $s2){
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s1); $i++)
        $arr[$s1[$i]] = 1;

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s2); $i++)
        if(!isset($arr[$s2[$i]]))
            return false;

    return true;
}

function _array_int($s1,$s2){
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s1); $i++)
        $arr[ord($s1[$i])] = 1;

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s2); $i++)
        if(!isset($arr[ord($s2[$i])]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

I thought the time complexity:
_sort(as func A) :    **O(nlgn)**
_array_int(as func B):  **O(n)**  
_strpos(as func C):     **O(n^2)**
thus speed seems to be **B>A>C**
but the test result is: **C>B>A**
I could not explain why C is fastest.

test it like this **php test.php test_count word_lenght test_func**

Comment: How fast/slow would it be if you sorted both arrays alphabetically and compared the strings with `==` ?

Comment: you can also use `strstr`

Comment: I'm assuming you meant **C** was the fastest in your tests, since you seem to be using `>` as "faster" when you say "speed seems to be `O(n) > O(nlgn) > O(n²)`

Comment: sorry, i mean C is fastest and i modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons your O(n^2) might have performed faster than the others, is because it contains a bug.

```
if(!strpos($s1,$s2[$i]))
        return false;
```

This effectively means "if there is no character `$s2[$i]` in `$s1` **OR** it is the **FIRST** character in $s1, return false.", since string index starts at 0. And that's probably not what you intended, as it will instantly return `false` in `O(1)` when both strings start with the same character, for example. *(you can fix this by using instead* `if(strpos($s1,$s2[$i]) === false)`)

Secondly, the input you use to test is critical for the results you obtain. Since `O(10*n)` is still `O(n)`, there is no guarantee that for small inputs, an `O(n)` algorithm will execute faster than a `O(n²)` and so on. This guarantee is on the asymptotic result as `n` grows sufficiently large. Besides, peculiarities in the algorithms can also lead to different performance in specific cases, as opposed to the "worst case". For example, your quadratic function could result in very different performances **compared to itself** by simply passing the arguments in swapped order `($s2, $s1)`, if one of the strings is significantly smaller than the other, or other special conditions are met, particularly because you allow your algorithms to quickly return `false` as soon as possible, without necessarily processing both strings all the way to the end.

In the end, your `O(n)` algorithm should generally perform the best among the 3, especially as the input size increases, but it is not necessarily guaranteed that it will perform better at **every** input.

Comment: thanks for your patiently explain and finding my bug.  i've add my test code in my question.i change the word lenght from 20 to 200000 ,still _array works not better than _strpos.

Answer (score -1):

if you simply use `str_split` to match if a string is part of another string. Your code seems unnecessarily complex.

```
  $string1 = "ABCD";
  $string2 = "AABCDEF";

  $origin = str_split($string1);
  $other = str_split($string2);

  foreach ($origin as $char) {
      if (in_array($char, $other)) {
          //char found
      } else {
          //char not found
      }
  }
```

Comment: This is not what he wants. He wants to check whether every letter is present, not whether it is a substring.

Comment: @Arthur ok take a look at it now

Comment: I'm not trying to find the substr, but just to test if every letter in word B appears in word A whithout order

Comment: that's a way to solve the proble，and I give three ways, i want to figure out which's most efficient.my test is not same with my guess and i am puzzled.;)